# Proving the product of two non singular matrices is also non singular.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having trouble with a proof for linear algebra. Could somebody explain to me how to prove that if $A$ and $B$ are both $n\times n$ non singular matrices, that their product $AB$ is also non singular.

A place to start would be helpful. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You should check out the following article. Well I mean other's searching for the proof: https://yutsumura.com/two-matrices-are-nonsingular-if-and-only-if-the-product-is-nonsingular/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that a matrix is non-singular if and only if it has an inverse.

Suppose $A$ and $B$ have inverses $A^{-1} B^{-1}$.  What do you get when you multiply
$$
(AB)(B^{-1}A^{-1})
$$
and why can we now conclude that $AB$ is non-singular?

Comment: Ok thanks I think this helps me out a lot.

Answer (score 8):

There's different manners to prove this result for example:

- Using the determinant:
  $$\det(AB)=\det A\det B$$
  and the fact that $C$ is singular iff $\det C=0$.
- Using the fact that $AB$ is invertible then $A$ is surjective and $B$ is injective and that in finite dimensional space: $C$ is injective iff $C$ is surjective iff $C$ is bijective.

Comment: How'd this go without an upvote?

Comment: @amWhy can you please elaborate more on second approach? Didnt get anything...Any web links for the relevant basics?

Answer (score 1):

Depends how far into linear algebra you are and what you can use. One possible and very short solution: a square matrix is nonsingular iff its determinant is nonzero. Now use the property for $\det(AB)$.

Comment: I haven't gotten this far yet, but thank you.